# Given a quadrilateral, find the ratio of line segments

Tags: geometry

> There is a quadrilateral $ABCD$ s.t. $\vec{DC}=\frac{3}{2}\vec{AB}$. There is a point $N\in BC$ s.t. $\vec{BN}=\frac{2}{5}\vec{BC}$. $Y$ is the intersection point of $AN$ and $BD$.
>   Find: $$\frac{|AY|}{|YN|}\;\;\&\;\;\frac{|BY|}{|YD|}$$

My attempt:
$$\vec{DC}=\frac{3}{2}\vec{AB}\implies AB\parallel CD\implies ABCD\;\;\text{is at least a trapezium}$$
[image]
Let $AM\parallel BC$ and let $S$ be the intersection point of $AM$ and $BD$.

$$\implies\Delta BNY{\sim}\Delta SAY\;\;\&\;\;\Delta ABS{\sim}\Delta SMD\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
$$|DM|=|CD|-|CM|=\frac{3}{2}|AB|-|AB|=\frac{1}{2}|AB|$$
$$\implies\frac{|AB|}{|DM|}=2\;\land\;(1)\implies\frac{|AS|}{|SM|}=2\;\;\;\;(2)$$
$$\implies |AS|=\frac{2}{3}|BC|\implies \frac{|AS|}{|BN|}=\frac{\frac{2}{3}|BC|}{\frac{2}{5}|BC|}=\frac{5}{3}$$
$$\implies\frac{|AY|}{|YN|}=\frac{5}{3}\;\;\land\;\;\frac{|BY|}{|YS|}=\frac{3}{5}$$

$$(2)\implies |DM|=\frac{|BY|+\frac{5}{3}|BY|}{2}=\frac{4}{3}|BY|$$
$$\implies\frac{|BY|}{|YD|}=\frac{|BY|}{\frac{5}{3}|BY|+\frac{4}{3}|BY|}=\frac{1}{3}$$

So, my answer is:

> $$\frac{|AY|}{|YN|}=\frac{5}{3}\;\;\&\;\;\frac{|BY|}{|YD|}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: $AB\parallel CD$ is not clear enough and its deduction seems wrong. Is it?

Comment: @Piquito : this parallelism is an immediate consequence of $\vec{DC}=\frac{3}{2}\vec{AB}$.

Comment: Oh yes. I thought in terms of  non vectorial magnitude . I am sorry.